# Make a php file runnable only once

Tags: php, file-io, file-permissions

I've seen fairly similar questions but none that have answered my whole use case. I have a file that I wan't to run once, and ONLY once. I'll have no access to a DB so my idea is to create a file that will mark (By it's existence) that the script has already been called once. I'm new to Linux file and directory permissions and have only had some hours to wrap my head around it. I'm still unclear on a lot of scenarios.

Will PHP by default be allowed to create a file in the same folder as the script or do I and anyone else that implements this, need to explicitly set permissions? I notice that the owner and group differs between the file created by netbeans and that created by the php-script

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 anders anders  658 Jul 28 23:27 setup.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup   0 Jul 28 23:28 from_setup_script.txt
```

So what do I have to be aware off if I go along with this solution, or is there anyone proclaiming a better way to solve the above case?

Comment: its all depended on your PHP configuration, the folder that the script sits in will need to have the proper permissions to allow php to write a new file.

Comment: seems like you could test all this for yourself in a couple of minutes

Comment: yes for my setup i can test this, but i'm concerned for what ever might happen if it is used on another server.

Comment: if you cant control the server permissions, then this wont work

Answer (score 0):

you can program that your php add  `<?php exit; ?>` at the beginning of your file when the file excuted 
i mean rewrite your php file. very simple here is what you
[fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to open your file. you should use w+ for this purpose 
and then [fwite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: You might encounter file permission restrictions in this case as well, I'm afraid. I think I might have to add an exception handling these cases.

Answer (score -3):

You could use a session variable, i.e.:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['isRunnable'] = true;

if ($_SESSION['isRunnable']) {
    // run...
    $_SESSION['isRunnable'] = false;
}
```

Comment: his script is made to be run only once ever ... not per user session

Comment: a session is unique to each visitor and is on top of that only temporary.